# Jenkins Exclude Regions with Git needs workspace (trigger a build unnecessarily)

Tags: jenkins, cloudbees

We have a git repo that has the following directory structure:

```
src/
test/
terraform/
```

Whenever someone does a commit to the repo, git sends a message to Jenkins to trigger a build. Perfect!

Except we do not want to trigger a build if someone does a commit to the terraform directory, so we've added an "excluded regions":

[image: git settings]

Everything works great, except we have dynamic executors, and when there are no executors, a build gets triggered even if someone does a commit to the terraform directory.

Basically, git needs to trigger a build to get a workspace.  Kinda defeats the whole purpose:

```
Scheduling a new build to get a workspace. (nonexisting_workspace)
```

This bug is reported as "functions as designed":
https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-18079

Is there any way to use "Excluded Region" in Jenkins if we are using dynamic executors?